# Java | Duplicate characters on Windows 8 CMD UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, cmd

I was trying to make cmd display UTF-8 encoded texts and I was finally able to do that.

I wrote a class containing the following code in order to make java write characters encoded in UTF-8:

```
        String text = "çşğüöıÇŞĞÜÖİ UTF-8 (65001)";
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "utf8"));
        System.out.println(text);
```

In command line, I entered the command `chcp 65001` before running the class, in order to change the encoding setting of commandline.

Anyway, after doing all these stuff I was finally able to print UTF-8 encoded characters. But I had a problem:

The output was supposed to look like this

```
çşğüöıÇŞĞÜÖİ UTF-8 (65001)
```

Instead the output was as follows:

```
çşğüöıÇŞĞÜÖİ UTF-8 (65001)TF-8 (65001)
```

It duplicates some of the characters and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: I won Tumbleweed badge thanks to this question..

Answer (score 0):

> It duplicates some of the characters and I couldn't figure out why.

Because the Windows console does not handle utf-8 properly.